# error: non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I got this code from a text book.

```
 class FirstClass
 {
     int idNo =25;
     public static void print()
     {
         System.out.println("firstclass citizen " + idNo);
     }
 }
 class SecondClass
 {
     int idNo =24;
     public static void print()
     {
         System.out.println("secondclass citizen" + idNo);
     }
 }
 public class People
 {
     //FirstClass female;
     //SecondClass male;
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         System.out.println("people from java world");
         FirstClass.print();
         SecondClass.print();
     }
 }
```

But when compiling this code I got the following errors

```
People.java:7: error: non-static variable idNo cannot be referenced from a stati
c context
            System.out.println("firstclass citizen " + idNo);
                                                       ^
People.java:16: error: non-static variable idNo cannot be referenced from a stat
ic context
            System.out.println("secondclass citizen" + idNo);
                                                       ^
2 errors
```

Comment: -1 because 1) the title and actual problem do not agree 2) there are many duplicates, just *search for the error* - i.e. `[java] non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`. I hope this question is deleted soon: you could speed up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refer to current Object, you can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this. **But you can not use `this` reference in static context(method or block)**.

`static` method can be called without creating object of that class. So if you use this or non-static variable into the static context it will create compilation error.

Comment: I changed as per your answer. Question also. Error changed to People.java:7: error: non-static variable idNo cannot be referenced from a stati
c context
                System.out.println("firstclass citizen " + idNo);
                                                           ^
People.java:16: error: non-static variable idNo cannot be referenced from a stat
ic context
                System.out.println("secondclass citizen" + idNo);
                                                           ^
2 errors

Comment: First I don't understand why -1? your class member variable are non-static so you can not use those in static method or block.

Comment: I changed my question as per your answer. Both code and error. Please have a look. Now there is no "this". But still error is there

Comment: your class member variable are non-static so you can not use those in static method or block. yes @Neeraj I have updated my answer's last part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create instances of the classes, and turn the methods into instance methods rather than static methods.

```
public class FirstClass {

    private int idNo = 25;        

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("firstclass citizen " + this.idNo);
    }
}
```

and then from the main method:

```
FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
fc.print();
```

Comment: I forgot to include idNo in my sample code. I've updated my example.

Answer (score -1):

You can't reference a non static attribute and use this into a static method, ie,

```
class FirstClass
{
    static int idNo =25;
    public static void print()
    {
            System.out.println("firstclass citizen " + idNo);
    }
}
class SecondClass
{
    static int idNo =24;
    public static void print()
    {
            System.out.println("secondclass citizen" + idNo);
    }
}
public class People
{
    FirstClass female;
    SecondClass male;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            System.out.println("people from java world");
            FirstClass.print();
            SecondClass.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: People.java:7: error: non-static variable idNo cannot be referenced from a stati
c context
                System.out.println("firstclass citizen " + idNo);
                                                           ^
People.java:16: error: non-static variable idNo cannot be referenced from a stat
ic context
                System.out.println("secondclass citizen" + idNo);
                                                           ^
2 errors   This is the error for your answer

Comment: -1 Your classes also need to be static if you want them to have static methods and variables.

Comment: The class doen't need to be static. Only the attributes. Did you put the static word before each attribute?